# Cannot connect via SSL using self signed certificate on Android 7 and above

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am using standard way to connect to SSL server with self signed certificate described here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html for the "Unknown certificate authority".

Everything works up to the Android 7.

On Android 7 and above I am getting Certificate exception with the message: "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

The only thing I managed to do is to create an "empty" X509TrustManager which accepts all certificates:

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] 
{
  new javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager() {
  @Override
  public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }

 @Override
 public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}

 @Override
 public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { }
};

//and then
 sSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 sSslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
```

but when I am adding the verification to the checkServerTrusted function:

```
 public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] 
                   chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        ((X509TrustManager) trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }
```

everything remains the same

I also checked the sources of the conscrypt library and I see that **checkTrusted** function puts the leaf to the untrusted chain if leafAsAnchor == null which is the case.

So is that possible to use self-signed certificate in this way or no?

Comment: I recommend that you use [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) on Android 7.0+ for self-signed certificates. If you want the same code for older devices, I backported [network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) to Android 4.2+.

Comment: How could I initialise ssl context in that case? I need it because it is used by other parts of the software.

Comment: "How could I initialise ssl context in that case?" -- you wouldn't, if you are using the native Android 7.0+ implementation. At most, you would use a vanilla `SSLContext`, without any custom configuration, but that might interfere with network security configuration (I haven't tried that scenario). "I need it because it is used by other parts of the software" -- why? Android 7.0 automatically applies the self-signed certificate for every Java socket.